# Aligning <Div> tags within a page

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

    $i =0;
    for($i=0; $i< 5; $i++) {
        echo'<div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;"><br> '.$i.'</div>';
    }

    for($i=4; $i>= 0; $i--) {
        echo'<div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;"><br> '.$i.'</div>';
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

See it working:

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;">
         <br>0
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;">
         <br>1
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;">
         <br>2
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;">
         <br>3
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-left:-120px;">
         <br>4
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;">
         <br>4
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;">
         <br>3
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;">
         <br>2
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;">
         <br>1
      </div>
      <div class="bloc" style="text-align:center; margin-right:-120px;">
         <br>0
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Where I'm trying to print the numbers 0-4 and 4-0 in the middle of the page, where one is a bit right of the middle, and the other a bit left (margins).
I want the output to look like this:

```
                             0 4 
                             1 3
                             2 2
                             3 1
                             4 0
```

Where the increasing numbers would be in the center minus 120 pixels to the left, and decreasing would be in the center minus 120 pixels to the right

I've tried adding the CSS:

```
.bloc{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

But that seems to place all the numbers in one spot, not the way I'd like them to be pictured. I also tried using the `<span>` tag which yielded the same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could group them, and set the width to 50% to make sure they're centred correctly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .bloc{
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }
        .bloc > div{
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
        .text-right{
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='bloc'>
    <?php for($i=0; $i< 5; $i++) : ?>
        <?php echo '<div class="text-right">'.$i.'</div>'; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='bloc'>
    <?php for($i=4; $i>= 0; $i--) : ?>
        <?php echo '<div>'.$i.'</div>'; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could actually try

1. using padding instead of margin
2. it'd be more easy to create a wrapper with an margin 0 auto and auto width where elements will have no float.
3. You could try some tricks with :nth-child(even). See here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp
4. You could try to read about flex box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Maybe I misunderstood your question. Don't hesitate to reply.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .halfDiv{
        width:50%;
    }
    .left{
        float:left;
    }
    .right{
        float:right;
    }
</style>

<div class="halfDiv left">
<?php
$i =0;
for($i=0; $i< 5; $i++) {
echo'<div class="right">'.$i.'-</div><br>';
}

?>
</div>
<div class="halfDiv right">
<?php
for($i=4; $i>= 0; $i--) {
echo'<div class="left"> '.$i.'</div><br>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.leftdiv,.rightdiv{display:inline-block;}
.parent{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="parent"><div class="leftdiv"><div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div></div>
  <div class="rightdiv"><div>4</div><div>3</div><div>2</div><div>1</div><div>0</div></div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your table in one LOOP like this.

```
<body>
    <table style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto">
        <?php
        $limit = 4;
        for ( $i = 0, $j = $limit; $i <= $limit & $j >= 0; $i++, $j-- ) {
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>". "$i" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". "$j" . "</td>";

            echo "<tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>

</body>
```

```html
<table style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div id="main">
<?php
    for($i=0; $i< 5; $i++) {
        echo'<div class="left"><br> '.$i.'</div>';
        for($j=4-$i; $j<5-$i; $j++){
            echo'<div class="right"><br> '.$j.'</div>';
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
    .left{
        float:left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .right{
        float:left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #main{
        width: 200px;
    }       
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As PHP, you can use that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    .bloc{display: inline-block; width: 49%;}
    .left{text-align: right; padding-right:0.5%;}
    .right{text-align: left; padding-left:0.5%;}
</style>
<?php
    $i =0;
    for($i=0; $i< 5; $i++) {
        echo'<div class="bloc left">'.$i.'</div>';
        echo'<div class="bloc right">'.(4-$i).'</div>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

As snippet

```css
.bloc{display: inline-block; width: 49%;}
.left{text-align: right; padding-right:0.5%;}
.right{text-align: left; padding-left:0.5%;}
```

```html
<div class="bloc left">0</div>
<div class="bloc right">4</div>
<div class="bloc left">1</div>
<div class="bloc right">3</div>
<div class="bloc left">2</div>
<div class="bloc right">2</div>
<div class="bloc left">3</div>
<div class="bloc right">1</div>
<div class="bloc left">4</div>
<div class="bloc right">0</div>
```